# How do I enable full OData functionality in .NET Core 5.0 WebAPI solution?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, odata, webapi

I'm having trouble getting OData to work in a new .NET Core WebAPI solution (.NET 5.0).

I am getting data back via the standard "/api/entity" and using a custom filter, but I'd much prefer using the OData built-in $select, $filter, $count, $metadata, etc. features.

I've added the nuget package for Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData v7.5.8, and added the following to my Startup.cs:

```
ConfigureServices()...    
services.AddOData();
    
Configure()...
endpoints.MapODataRoute("odata", "odata", GetEdmModel()).Select().Filter().Expand().Count();
```

And the EDM Model method:

```
private static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
        {
            ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new();
            builder.EntitySet<Event>("Events");
            return builder.GetEdmModel();
        }
```

Everything compiles, and if I hit `[rooturl]/odata`, I see my entity, so I see it's basically working (I think).

However if I go to: `[rooturl]/odata/events(1)` I get page not found... however if I use the default `[rooturl]/api/events/1` route, it works perfectly.

This is my first .NET Core WebAPI, after building countless .NET Standard WebForms, WCF, MVC, and WebAPI solutions. I am sure I'm just missing something simple... but I cannot figure out what.

I would like to be able to use OData like this:

```
[rooturl]/odata/Events?$top=10
[rooturl]/odata/Events?$filter=name eq "foo"
[rooturl]/odata/Events?$select=id,name,status
```

In .NET Standard MVC, OData functionality was available right off the bat. How do I get that with .NET Core?

Anyone have suggestions on what to add to get this wired up properly?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After referring to one of my old WebAPI solutions (.NET Framework 4.8 MVC), I figured it out. Thankfully, most of the old patterns still work in .NET Core.

*Posting the solution for those who may run into the same issues.*

The Startup.cs needs the following code:

```
ConfigureServices()...
services.AddOData();

Configure()...
// removed app.UseUseMvc()...replaced with this...

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    //endpoints.EnableDependencyInjection();
    endpoints.Select()
             .OrderBy()
             .Filter()
             .SkipToken()
             .MaxTop(null)
             .Expand()
             .Count();
    endpoints.MapODataRoute("api", "api", GetEdmModel());
});

GetEdmModel()...
ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new();
var events = builder.EntitySet<Events>("Events");            
return builder.GetEdmModel();
```

On the controller:

Add annotation `[EnableQuery]` to methods.
Set output to `IQueryable<Events>` (and make sure you return the collection `AsQueryable()`.

That did the trick and now I'm seeing all the OData options I need for this collection.

Comment: Thumbup!  By the way, there's a new 8.0 version coming. See at: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/odata/asp-net-odata-8-0-preview-for-net-5/